# Restful service take data from database and return into json

Tags: json, rest

I am creating one rest service which take data from database and return into json format.but at one place I trapped.till now i fetched data from data base but i don't know how to convert that data into json. so can you help now what i have to do next

***IWcfDataService.cs***

```
namespace RestWCFService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWcfDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "Search/{keyword}")]
        Detail Search(string keyword);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Detail
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string student_id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }


    } 
}
```

***WcfDataService.svc***

```
namespace RestWCFService
{

    public class WcfDataService : IWcfDataService
    {

        public Detail Search(string keyword)
        {



               var json = "";
                var data = "";


                 SqlConnection sql_Search;


                 sql_Search = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FPBLWD0309;Initial Catalog=student_info;Integrated Security=True");
                 sql_Search.Open();

                 SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Student_ID,First_Name,Last_Name FROM record Where (First_Name Like '%" + keyword + "%')", sql_Search);


                 SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
                 SqlDataReader read = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                 while (read.Read())
                 {
                     var De = new Detail { 
                       student_id = read["student_ID"].ToString(),
                       First_Name = read["First_Name"].ToString(),
                       Last_Name  = read["Last_Name"].ToString()
                    };

                 }


           return De;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to make HTTP Web APIs (aka REST APIs) using C# then I strongly recommend that you use ASP NET Web API instead of WPF (see http://www.asp.net/web-api).